# AngularJS Access DOM from service

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS page which renders a map using OpenLayers.

I am looking to add an overlay to the map so that it can be clicked to display some information. Unfortunately I can't seem to reference the DOM elements required from the service.

I am trying to avoid putting a `<script>` tag inside the HTML partial for the page.

If anyone has a better way of doing this I am all ears. I am new to AngularJS.

**`main.html`** (partial)

```
<h2>My Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
  <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
  <div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>

<script src="Stylesheets/map.css"></script>
```

**`main.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", function($scope, openlayers){
    openlayers.init();
    $scope.selected = openlayers.selected;
});
```

**`openlayers.js`**

```
angular.module("app").factory("openlayers", function($document){

    var init = function(){

        /*
         * Elements that make up the popup.
         */
        var container = $document[0].getElementById('popup');
        var content = $document[0].getElementById('popup-content');
        var closer = $document[0].getElementById('popup-closer');
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        selected: activeVector,
        cities: cities
    };

});
```

Comment: You may want to create a directive rather than a service.

Comment: You can't inject scope into services for a reason.

Comment: @lux - that's very unhelpful. Next time it would be good for you to recommend the proper way to do it - I am clearly new to AngularJS so what is obvious to you may not immediately be obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the service via DOM is not a good practice . The ***service*** should be used to communicate data between ***controlers*** and not to change DOM data. If you want to create a generic method can create a module "***commons***" to encapsulate them and provide access to other controllers.

It is possible for you to use a ***directive*** to manipulate DOM data. This is recommended when you want to write elements / behavior from custom elements.

**Look this example with directive:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainController', function($scope, openlayers){
    console.log('Container: ' + $scope.container);
    console.log('Content:   ' + $scope.content);
    console.log('Closer:    ' + $scope.closer);
});

angular.module('app', []).directive('openlayersDirective',  function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element) {
            var init = function(){
                $scope.container = angular.element(element).find('#popup');
                $scope.content   = angular.element(element).find('#popup-content');
                $scope.closer    = angular.element(element).find('#popup-closer');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**In html put directive:**

```
<body openlayersDirective>
    <div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: A directive is not always suitable, for example, when wanting to show a popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can access DOM elements via Angular's [jqLite](http://jeep_wrangler.png).

But as for a better way to do this, I'd simply use `position: absolute` to put the overlay element over your main element, and use `ngClick` like so:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)
;

function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.fn = function() {
    console.log('foo');
  };
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>


<div class='wrapper' ng-app='app' ng-controller='MainController'>
  <div class='main'></div>
  <div class='overlay' ng-click='fn()'></div>
</div>
```